# Why I can't initiate a bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I want to initiate a bounty for one of my question [Link here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46554/how-can-i-enable-fast-printing-from-firefox-cups-on-ubuntu-10-10) and as per FAQ the question should be atleast 2 days old. Now the question is more than 2 days old and I still cannot initiate a bounty. Why is that ?
More  over the next to my question I get a note "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" which makes me wonder more why I cannot offer bounty to this question.

The FAQ states: 
1.Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
2.Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
3. There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.

Does the third point means, I can offer bounty for only ONE question ?
I already have another question where I offered the bounty. Also the last edit of the question is not 2 days old. Since I am not sure if it is a bug, I am not tagging it as a bug yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only have one active bounty at a time - since it appears you already have another bounty, you can not create another until you either award that bounty or it expires.

Update: As of [September 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104813/), you may have 3 active bounties at a time.