# No option found to start a bounty

Tags: support, bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why I can't initiate a bounty](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1466/why-i-cant-initiate-a-bounty)

I have started a question which is quite old now and i din get any clear solution to that question still. So i thought to start a bounty for my question but i don see any option in that question. Please look at the screenshot. Is it a bug?
[image: Bounty]

Comment: In the very moment this question was posted I could start a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one bounty at a time, see the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty):

> There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.

Currently, you've put a bounty on [How to copy/paste text from remote system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/41273/6969)