# "start a bounty" missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

I have a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195011/screen-brightness) for which I want to start a bounty. The "start a bounty" is missing.

I checked [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1466/why-i-cant-initiate-a-bounty) before asking here and I learnt that, per user account only one active bounty is allowed. Is only one active bounty allowed per user, all his stackexchange accounts puttogether? However, that - for the moment - is academic interest only, because I checked I have no active bounties on any of my stack exchange accounts.

I read through the page on all about bounties, and found that as regards the age of the question, the lower limit is 2 days which is clear in fact at the moment one posts his question.

But the question in concern was asked in 2012. So is there a tacit upper limit on the age of the question for starting a bounty??

Comment: Jorge Castro was kind enough to put a 150 point bounty on the question

Comment: Thanks Jorge Castro!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You need to have more than 75 reputation.](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties)

Comment: Really overlooked that! Sorry